# How to Splice specific Letter From Arrays Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, splice

Is there a way to remove a specific character from arrays using the splice method? or any other method for that matter. I want to remove the letter 'W' that is attached to the numbers below. Thanks for your time! The best I could get was removing the entire part i.e "9W" rather than just having "9" left

```
   const sales = filteredProducts.map(function(product) {
    return {
        lastSaleSize: product.market.lastSaleSize,
        lastSale: product.market.lastSale,

      }
})
console.log(sales)

const newArr = sales.map((prev) => {
  const {
    lastSaleSize
  } = prev;
  const newLastSaleSize = lastSaleSize.match(/(.+?)W/, 'g')[1];
  const newElement = { ...prev,
    lastSaleSize: newLastSaleSize
  };
  return newElement;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

```
sales = 
0: {lastSaleSize: "9W", lastSale: 185}
1: {lastSaleSize: "8.5W", lastSale: 190}
2: {lastSaleSize: "11W", lastSale: 182}
3: {lastSaleSize: "9.5W", lastSale: 170}
4: {lastSaleSize: "9W", lastSale: 185}
5: {lastSaleSize: "7W", lastSale: 185}
6: {lastSaleSize: "8W", lastSale: 174}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're after is the `map` function, which iterates an array and returns a new (calculated) value in place of each of the original array's elements:

```js
const arr = [
  {lastSaleSize: "9W", lastSale: 172},
  {lastSaleSize: "8.5W", lastSale: 190},
  {lastSaleSize: "11W", lastSale: 182},
  {lastSaleSize: "9.5W", lastSale: 170},
  {lastSaleSize: "7W", lastSale: 185},
  {lastSaleSize: "8W", lastSale: 174},
  {lastSaleSize: "10W", lastSale: 189},
  {lastSaleSize: "12W", lastSale: 185},
];

// You can use other methods, obviously
function removeW(string) {
  return string.match(/(.+?)W/)[1];
}

const newArr = arr.map((prevElement) => {
  const { lastSaleSize } = prevElement; // Get the lastSaleSize value for the current element
  const newLastSaleSize = removeW(lastSaleSize);
  
  // Now generate the new Element, without the 'W'
  const newElement = {
    ...prevElement,
    lastSaleSize: newLastSaleSize,
  };
  return newElement;
});

console.log(newArr);
```

Comment: yes! this works, thank you! I was looking into maps, but didn't know enough to do what you just did. thank you!

Comment: if you have the time can you explain to me why this isn't working? I've put the code above

Comment: You didn't define `filteredProducts` and `sales` is defined twice and is also misplaced

Answer (score 0):

you can use splice method of javascript to remove last character in your case it is "W". if the character appears to be random in your string you should use regex.

```
let str = "9W";
str = str.slice(0, -1); 
console.log(str);
```